# CPP MSVS Including header files across projects causing unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, project

I have 2 projects, containing 3 files

---

**ProjectOne**

> Entry.cpp **// Entry point, main()**

```
#include "../ProjectTwo/ExternalClass.h"

int main()
{
    ExternalClass::Function();
    return 1;
}
```

---

**ProjectTwo**

> ExternalClass.h **// ExternalClass::Function() Declaration**

```
#pragma once
class ExternalClass
{
public:
    static void Function();
};
```

> ExternalClass.cpp **// ExternalClass::Function() Definition**

```
#include "ExternalClass.h"

void ExternalClass::Function()
{
    return;
}
```

---

Project one includes project two's ExternalClass.h file.
In the entry point of project one, I call ExternalClass::Function(), In result I get

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl ExternalClass::Function(void)" (?Function@ExternalClass@@SAXXZ) referenced in function _main    ProjectOne  ...\ProjectOne\Entry.obj    1

In attempt to fix this I tried making project one dependant on project two, I set project two to a project with no entry point, and it builds as a utility file,

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean 'cppml' ?

Comment: Ah, apologise, It was an oversite when making the question,